# Timezone conversion after passing value from lwc to apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Scenario is

1. My country timezone/system timezone is GMT+5:30 and My salesforce org timezone is GMT+0.
2. I am creating a record with value in datetime field say **createdDateTime** as **2 aug 5:00 am**
3. I have an lwc component which is fetching value of **createdDateTime** of record using wire method and after value is fetched i console log/print value of **createdDateTime** from lwc component and output is **2 aug 5:00 am** as expected.
4. i send **createdDateTime** from lwc to apex class for creation of some other record but i find the value of **createdDateTime** in apex upon printing to be **1 aug 23:30 pm** that is 5:30 is getting deducted from it automatically.
   5.when i save the record the **createdDateTime** field value after record creation is **1 aug 23:30 pm** .
   6.How can i ensure the **createdDateTime** field value is **2 aug 5:00 am** as was fetched originally?
   7.How can i also make sure that above scenario holds true for person having country timezone/system timezone as well as salesforce timezone as gmt+0 ?

Comment: DateTime fields store the time information in UTC and display the appropriate date and time to the user based on the user's personal timezone settings.

one thing you need to make sure of is to save the correct UTC value into the dateFields.

Comment: Without a reproduction that we can use to examine your code closely, there's no way we can help you. I can tell you that it does work, because otherwise it would be useless to set date/time values in LWC/Apex, but without knowing what you did, it's impossible to tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce stores time in UTC in the DB. Then runtime using the company settings and the user`s time zone settings this time is dynamically shown in the right time zone for the current user.

In order to get the desired result you should keep in mind those things and use APEX to access company time zone and user`s time zone.

```
//Getting the organization Time Zone Key
        Organization orgInfo = [Select TimezoneSidKey FROM Organization];
```

I have an article that can help you understand this:
https://bflow.dev/salesforce-createddate-to-localorg-time-zone/